# Getting JSON array of data using POST method using HttpUrlConnection in Android

Tags: json, httpurlconnection

I want to do an API call using `HttpUrlConnection` for POST as the JSON content looks like this

To POST I need to pass key as id and value as 1234.

```
{
    "message": "Success",
    "constituency": [{
        "id": "1",
        "constituency_name": "abc"
    }, {
        "id": "2",
        "constituency_name": "def"
    }]
}
```

I need to fetch this array of strings. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you clarify your requirements a bit more, please?

Answer (score -1):

```
jsonObj = new JSONObject(response);
jsonData = jsonObj.optJSONObject("data");
JSONArray arrJson = jsonData.getJSONArray("numbers");
String[] arr = new String[arrJson.length()];
for(int i = 0; i < arrJson.length(); i++)
   arr[i] = arrJson.getString(i);
```

Comment: Thank you so much helped me alot :)